# R - create and name data frames from existing column values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that is structured like so, via `dput`:

```
structure(list(railroad = c("bnsf railway company", "bnsf railway company", 
"bnsf railway company", "bnsf railway company", "bnsf railway company", 
"bnsf railway company", "bnsf railway company", "bnsf railway company", 
"union pacific railroad", "union pacific railroad", "union pacific railroad", 
"union pacific railroad", "union pacific railroad", "union pacific railroad", 
"union pacific railroad", "union pacific railroad"), measure = 
c("cars.owned.by", 
"cars.owned.by", "cars.type", "cars.type", "cars.type", "train.speed", 
"train.speed", "terminal.dwell", "cars.owned.by", "cars.owned.by", 
"cars.type", "cars.type", "cars.type", "train.speed", "train.speed", 
"terminal.dwell"), category = c("system", "private", "box", "intermodal", 
"total", "intermodal", "all.trains", "entire.railroad", "system", 
"private", "box", "intermodal", "total", "intermodal", "all.trains", 
"entire.railroad"), irm = c(201510L, 201510L, 201510L, 201510L, 
201510L, 201510L, 201510L, 201510L, 201510L, 201510L, 201510L, 
201510L, 201510L, 201510L, 201510L, 201510L), mean = c(66623, 
149937.333, 11395, 16499, 236866, 33.3, 24.5, 25.267, 57618.333, 
195764.667, 22229.333, 14135.333, 293164.333, 31.933, 26.6, 27.6
)), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 14L, 15L, 20L, 32L, 127L, 129L, 
132L, 135L, 140L, 141L, 146L, 160L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I would like to do is the following:

1. Create separate data frames for each combination of `measure` and `category`,
   named by pasting `measure` and `category` separated by `"."`.  So the first data frame would be called `cars.owned.by.system` and so on.
2. Rename the fifth column, `mean` of each data frame to the name of the data frame itself. So, for the first data frame it would be `colnames(df)[5] <- cars.owned.by.system`.

The desired output is 8 separate data frames, named as I mentioned above

I tried the following:

```
cars.owned.by.system <- df[df$category == "system",]
colnames(cars.owned.by.system)[5[ <- cars.owned.by.system
```

And it does the job, but I don't want to have to do this repetitively.  I imagine there is a version of the canonical split-apply-combine approach that would work.  Any advice or help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Reconsider separate data frames and use a list of data frames (less objects to worry about in global environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `split` to subset data frame by the two factors and then `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) to iterate elementwise through subsetted data frames and list's names.

Also, consider `setNames()` the left-hand version of `colnames()` to return the new named object in one call.

```
# CREATES NAMED LIST
df_list <- split(df, list(df$measure, df$category))

# RETURNS SAME LIST WITH RENAMED FIFTH COLUMN
df_list <- Map(function(sub, nm) setNames(sub, c("railroad", "measure", "category", "irm", nm)), 
               df_list, names(df_list))

# OUTPUT DFs 
df_list$cars.owned.by.all.trains

df_list$cars.type.all.trains

df_list$terminal.dwell.all.trains 
...
```

Comment: is there a way to stack all of the non-empty elements of `df_list` via `rbind`?

Comment: Sure, but since you have different columns in each df use external libraries: `dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)` or `data.table::rbindlist(df_list)`. Otherwise you need to fill empty columns of other groups for all to have the same cols to use base R's `do.call(rbind, df_list)`.

Comment: By the way, I'm a big railroad guy. How did you get this freight data across the railroads? Proprietary or public data?

Comment: They only hold on to the most recent 52 weeks or so but it's easily scrapable so that if you run your script every week you can get the latest data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe, I think this does it.

```
for(cat in unique(df$category)) {
  newdf<-paste("cars.owned.by.", cat, sep="")
  assign(newdf, df[df$category==cat,])
  eval(parse(text=paste("colnames(", newdf, ")[5] <- '", newdf, "'", sep="")))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about a classical for loop:

```
# first create the pasted name to iterate the loop 
df$name <- paste(df$railroad,df$measure,sep='.')

# an empty list to have all your df
list_df <- list()

# the loop
for (i in df$name){
data <- df[which(df$name == i),]  # select the df of name
colnames(data)[4]<-i              # rename the mean
data<- data[,-5]                  # remove the useless name
list_df[[i]] <- data              # store in list
}

# here you can see all the df in a list
list_df

> list_df
$`bnsf railway company.cars.owned.by`
              railroad       measure category bnsf railway company.cars.owned.by                               name
1 bnsf railway company cars.owned.by   system                             201510 bnsf railway company.cars.owned.by
3 bnsf railway company cars.owned.by  private                             201510 bnsf railway company.cars.owned.by

$`bnsf railway company.cars.type`
               railroad   measure   category bnsf railway company.cars.type                           name
6  bnsf railway company cars.type        box                         201510 bnsf railway company.cars.type
9  bnsf railway company cars.type intermodal                         201510 bnsf railway company.cars.type
14 bnsf railway company cars.type      total                         201510 bnsf railway company.cars.type
... and so on  

# you can select each df, for example choosin its name
list_df$`bnsf railway company.cars.type`
                    railroad   measure   category bnsf railway company.cars.type                           name
6  bnsf railway company cars.type        box                         201510 bnsf railway company.cars.type
9  bnsf railway company cars.type intermodal                         201510 bnsf railway company.cars.type
14 bnsf railway company cars.type      total                         201510 bnsf railway company.cars.type

# and you're sure it's a df
class(list_df$`bnsf railway company.cars.type`)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a named list of dataframes, which is almost certainly preferable to having them all separately in your global environment:

```
lst <- split(df, paste(df$measure, df$category, sep = ".")) %>% 
  purrr::imap(~`names<-`(.x, c(names(.x)[1:4], .y)))
```

Comment: this is really efficient.  the only problem is it doesn't rename the 5th column

Comment: I missed that part -- edited my answer to rename the 5th column.